# R parallel with 12 cores

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I recently buyed a new computer with 12 cores.

I tried running an R script using the foreach package and the following commands:

```
cl <- makeCluster(12)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

However the task manager shows that only 4 cores are used (see snapshot below). Do you have an explanation for this ? Thanks.

[image]

Edit: As an example, I use the following code

```
sim <- foreach(j=1:nsim,.combine=c,
.packages=c('rugarch','stats'),.inorder=FALSE) %dopar%
{
exp(diffinv(ugarchsim(fit_list[["CHF"]],n.sim=horizon)@simulation$seriesSim))[horizon+1]
}
```

Edit 2: SessionInfo gives

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
 [1] parallel  splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
 [8] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] np_0.60-2          boot_1.3-13        doParallel_1.0.8   iterators_1.0.7   
 [5] foreach_1.4.2      scales_0.2.4       plyr_1.8.2         VineCopula_1.4    
 [9] rugarch_1.3-4      copula_0.999-13    caschrono_1.4      timeSeries_3012.99
[13] its_1.1.8          Hmisc_3.15-0       ggplot2_1.0.1      Formula_1.2-1     
[17] survival_2.37-7    lattice_0.20-29    forecast_5.9       timeDate_3012.100 
[21] zoo_1.7-12         urca_1.2-8         tseries_0.10-34   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] acepack_1.3-3.3             ADGofTest_0.3              
 [3] cluster_1.15.3              codetools_0.2-9            
 [5] colorspace_1.2-6            cubature_1.1-2             
 [7] digest_0.6.8                DistributionUtils_0.5-1    
 [9] expm_0.99-1.1               foreign_0.8-61             
[11] fracdiff_1.4-2              GeneralizedHyperbolic_0.8-1
[13] gsl_1.9-10                  gtable_0.1.2               
[15] igraph_0.7.1                KernSmooth_2.23-13         
[17] ks_1.9.4                    latticeExtra_0.6-26        
[19] MASS_7.3-35                 Matrix_1.1-4               
[21] misc3d_0.8-4                munsell_0.4.2              
[23] mvtnorm_1.0-2               nloptr_1.0.4               
[25] nnet_7.3-8                  numDeriv_2012.9-1          
[27] proto_0.3-10                pspline_1.0-16             
[29] quadprog_1.5-5              RColorBrewer_1.1-2         
[31] Rcpp_0.11.5                 reshape2_1.4.1             
[33] rgl_0.95.1201               rpart_4.1-8                
[35] Rsolnp_1.15                 SkewHyperbolic_0.3-2       
[37] spd_2.0-0                   stabledist_0.6-6           
[39] stats4_3.1.2                stringr_0.6.2              
[41] tools_3.1.2                 truncnorm_1.0-7            
[43] xts_0.9-7
```

Comment: It’s really impossible to say what may cause this since you didn’t show us the code that’s supposed to be run in parallel. The commands you’ve given us won’t actually execute any resource-intensive code, in parallel or otherwise.

Comment: Just a remark: I think the `rugarch` package has a parallel option (not sure whether for `ugarchsim` as well). You could try to use that option directly. How many `rscript.exe` processes have you running after you register the nodes?

Comment: Could yo u show what packages you are using (as Windows has a different implementation to Linux) –  what does `parallel::detectCores()` show?

Comment: I've added the output of SessionInfo. The output of `parallel::detecCores()` is 12.

Comment: ok good, thanks... its look as if you dont have the right packages. To use `foreach` on Windows, *i think* you need `doSNOW `package. But as a first step, try just using the `snow` package. Start a fresh R instance, then `library(snow);  cl <- makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())` and see the length of `cl`

Comment: Try `registerDoParallel(cores = 12)` (Also, you can simplify your syntax using `foreach:times` since `j` is not part of your function).

Comment: @user20650 I use `foreach` with `doParallel` on Windows.

Comment: ok... i only suggested the above snow commands to check that your cores are being detected and clusters formed. If so, then it is a problem of syntax.

Comment: @konvas I tried `registerDoParallel(cores = 12)` but the result is the same: 4 clusters working at 100% while the other ones remain (nearly) unactive.